# Probability about inverse of modulo $n$

Tags: probability, modular-arithmetic

If $\gcd(a,n)=1$, then the solution of $a \cdot x \equiv 1 \bmod n $ is $x \equiv a^{\varphi(n)-1} \bmod n$.  I want to know the probability of $Pr( (x\bmod n)> n/2)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not clear. I will assume that $a$ is chosen uniformly at random from the positive integers less than and coprime to $n$. In that case, $x$ is also distributed uniformly among the positive integers less than and coprime to $n$, and there are exactly as many of these greater than $n/2$ as less than $n/2$ (since $\gcd(b,n)=\gcd(n-b,n)$). So under this assumption, the probability is exactly $1/2$.

[There are a couple of trivial exceptions, when $n=1$ and when $n=2$, but these present no challenge.]